# VMware ESX/i syslog content

Tags: logging, esxi, syslog

I am working on an expansion of our monitoring footprint, and we are currently looking at including data from our visualized environment. As our monitoring license is based on logged volumes, and we are likely to need an increase in infrastructure. As part of this planning we are trying to gauge the value in logging the input, i.e. what information can we get out of the syslog messages.

I have been trying to details of possible syslog messages, however I have been unsuccessful. Is there a complete list of the syslog messages which can potentially appear in logging (even if we have to get this via our support contract)?

Additionally in planning, I have seen it mentioned that the content from two local log files are included in the syslog ouput. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a comprehensive list of all syslog messages.  Cisco has a list of their [messages here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa80/system/message/logmsgs.pdf&ei=fgo9UdylKozE9gT4qYDIDA&usg=AFQjCNFmb6k_JPmgbAX_8aD-D2fp3JzuqA&bvm=bv.43287494,d.eWU).  They have over 6,000, so that should be enough to get you started.

Comment: @"Tom Damon", I'm not sure what the relation between Cisco and VMware is?

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a great question (and a tough one).

To answer the first part of your question: I've never seen a list that contains ALL possible syslog messages for VMware.  I've never tried to ask support for this information though.

To answer the second part of your question: I do believe the syslog aggregates logging information from a few different places, but I believe it's more than just two.  I think it contains information on VMKernel warnings, VMKernel messages/alerts/etc., VM's kernel core file, the syslogd service, and some Service Console information as well.

I'm not sure what version of ESX you're running, but here is at least a small reference about [ESX 5.0 Logging](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.wssdk.pg.doc_50/PG_ChA_Diagnostics.19.3.html).